# How to change position of selected rows in lightning datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-datatable

I have lightning datable with multi selection,  I want to put all selected rows on top of the table is there a way to do that?

I can get current record with `component.find('auraid').getSelectedRows();` but no idea how to change selected row position to 1?

Here is attached screenshot. What I want to achieve - now Madisen, Arsen and Susanna should be on positions 1-3 and Will should be fourth.

Point is :
Everytime new row' checkbox is set to true he should be moved to row 1.

[image: datatable]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the table's data. One possible way to do this is to Array.sort.

```
let ids = component.find('auraid').map(row => row.id);
let rows = component.get('v.data');
rows.sort((a, b) => -ids.indexOf(a.id) - -ids.indexOf(b.id));
component.set('v.data', rows);
```

Other ways are also possible, such as using Array.filter:

```
let ids = component.find('auraid').map(row => row.id);
let rows = component.get('v.data');
let selected = rows.filter(row => ids.includes(row.id));
let others = rows.filter(row => !ids.includes(row.id));
rows = [...selected, ...others];
component.set('v.data', rows);
```

In summary, you just need to alter the underlying data to change the row order.

Comment: I deleted `id` and below code did job:
let ids = component.find('productsTable').getSelectedRows();
let rows = component.get('v.pricebookProductsFiltered');
let selected = rows.filter(row => ids.includes(row));
let others = rows.filter(row => !ids.includes(row));
rows = [...selected, ...others];
component.set('v.pricebookProductsFiltered', rows);
$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
THANK